# How to choose which Powershell version Jenkins should use?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am using [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/powershell/) Powershell plugin for my Jenkins build server. As you can see, one of the recent updates allows for selection of a Powershell version:

[image]

The version I have running on my server is 1.7. The problem arises when I try to actually change the version of Powershell, since the example given uses a scripted pipeline, whereas my project uses a declarative one, so the built-in option for version selection is missing. How can I force Jenkins to use Powershell 7.2 instead of the default 5.*?

The only solution I can think of is using Powershell 5 to start Powershell 7 and to then run my .ps1 script like that, but that seems *stupid*.

Comment: In both declarative and scripted pipeline you can use the [`pwsh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#pwsh-powershell-core-script) step to run a script in PS 7.x.

Comment: @zett42 It was indeed as simple as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both declarative and scripted pipeline you can use the [`pwsh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#pwsh-powershell-core-script) step to run a script in PS 7.x.

**Declarative:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                pwsh '''
                    Write-Host "foo"
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Scripted:**

```
node {
     pwsh '''
         Write-Host "foo"
     '''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it conditional. This script re-launches itself with version 7.2 only if the version is greater than 5.0.

if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -gt [Version]"5.0") {

powershell -Version 7.2 -File $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

exit

}

'run some code'

Read-Host -Prompt "Scripts Completed : Press any key to exit"

Comment: This *sort of* works. First off I need to check if the current version is less than version 7, and if it is, I need to relaunch with version 7. Second off, for whatever reason, no matter what version of Powershell I put in the body of the if-statement, I get a `Cannot start Windows PowerShell version X.Y because it is not installed.` error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. install the latest powershell-plugin for Jenkins
2. find the file "*.\Jenkins\hudson.plugins.powershell.PowerShellInstallation.xml*"
3. replace "**powershell.exe**" by "**pwsh.exe**" (see example below) -- providing a full path may also work
4. restart Jenkins

   ```
   <hudson.plugins.powershell.PowerShellInstallation>    
   <name>DefaultWindows</name>    
   <home>powershell.exe</home>    
   <properties/>
   ```